# How to scroll down to a section in homepage (/) from another page

Tags: html

I want the user to be referred to the homepage from another page, which is `/`, and scroll down to the section. Here's an HTML code that doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <a href="/#section-1">Section 1</a>
    <div id="section-1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If it were `index.html` (i.e `<a href="index.html#section-1">Section 1</a>`) , this would've worked, but it's not working on `/` only.

Comment: Can you be more specific than doesn't work? It is possible something other than `index.html` has been set as the default page. Are you hitting `index.html`?

Comment: @JonP it's not `index.html`, it's `/`, no html file, it's being rendered from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass some params to the URL `?section=section1`. When the `/` component mounts, check if params are present, scroll to the section programmatically: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: There should be a simpler solution but this does do the job for now, thanks.